# How do I recursively duplicate a List?

Tags: java, list, recursion, methods

Here's my code:

```
public class ListItem {

    final int number; //These need to stay this way because I need to access them later
    ListItem next;

    ListItem(int number, ListItem next) {
        this.number = number;
        this.next   = next;
    }

    // I need to return a copy of this list using recursion, not iteration.
    public ListItem duplicate() {
        if (duplicate() == ListItem) { //base case??
            return next;
        }
        else return duplicate(); //just a placeholder
   }
```

I am unsure of what the base case is supposed to be and what the recursive call would be since `duplicate()` takes no parameters. Could someone walk me through how Java sees these methods? I want to learn how this works.

Comment: “duplicate() takes no parameters” What about `this`? It's not really a parameter, but it acts pretty much like one. Also, when dealing with lists, the base case is almost always an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ListItem duplicate() {
    if (next == null) {
        // base case: last item in the chain
        return new ListItem(this.number, null);
    }
    else {
        // start by duplicating the rest of the chain:
        ListItem newNext = next.duplicate();
        return new ListItem(this.number, newNext);
    }
}
```

or, more concisely:

```
public ListItem duplicate() {
    ListItem newNext = next == null ? null : next.duplicate();
    return new ListItem(this.number, newNext);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learned the syntax for the bottom, more concise, version but I understand what you did at the top. Thanks again!